# Разряд местоимения У КОГО

Tags: морфология

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, к какому разряду относится местоимение У КОГО в предложении: Что у кого болит, тот о том и говорит.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос был о разряде. "У кого" - это относительно-вопросительное местоимение "кто" в род. пад. В данном случае оно относительное, т.к. нет вопроса. А в предложении местоимений может быль сколько угодно. В том числе и одного разряда.

> Получается в одном придаточном два союзных слова.

Союзное слово одно - "что". В данном случае это вопросительное местоимение, так как относительные местоимения связывают два простых предложения в составе сложного

Comment: Понятно. Но  относительное местоимение вроде как должно  присоединять
придаточное к главному. Получается в одном  придаточном два союзных слова.

Comment: Так роль  относительного  местоимения-союзное слово!

Comment: У относительного местоимения 2 роли: основная синтаксическая роль-подлежащее или дополнение, но, кроме этого,оно может присоединять придаточное к главному, тогда оно является союзным словом.Что(подлежащее, союзное слово) у кого(дополнение, союзным словом не является) болит, тот о том и говорит.

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении это относительное местоимение

Comment: А чем тогда является слово ЧТО? Еще одно относительное местоимение? Так бывает?

Comment: "Что" - это подлежащее, выраженное относительным местоимением, а "у кого" - это дополнение